# Why doesn't getting the handle of the foreground window work in my scenario?

Tags: c#, windows, focus

I have the wonderful job to create a .exe that is called with a shortcut that is called with the windows native shortcut calling way for elements that are in the start menu folder.
It is supposed to **do something with one selected file of the topmost Explorer window.**
I have found ways to find all selected files across all explorer windows, I know how to get the window handle of the topmost window and I knew how to get all files selected in the topmost window **if getting the topmost window handle would work, which it doesn't in my case**:

Calling the native method **GetForegroundWindow() doesn't give me the handle of the top window**, but another one, maybe the one of the program I wrote, which doesn't even use a console window or anything though visible, so I can't even check if it's a handle from my program without changing it in a way to display the console.

***I want to get the handle of the foreground window by using a keyboard combination that was set in the options of a shortcut.
How do I get the window that was in the foreground before I called my program?
Or how do I keep my program from stealing focus?
Or how do I give the focus back to the last window that had it? / Take it away from the current one.
Or how do I get the topmost window of a specific process? (explorer)***

Comment: There is no good way to do this from a startup folder shortcut.  You have no idea what other programs may be started on the user's machine.  Or in what order they got started.  Or which one will get the foreground.  Getting your program to stop stealing the foreground is simple, don't create a window.  The ShellWindows COM object can iterate Explorer windows.

Comment: I am not creating any windows: I am not referencing windows forms, wpf or the Console. Startup type: "Windows application". I found a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

"Or how do I keep my program from stealing focus?"

Try this out...

Add this code to your Form:

```
    private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x8000000;

    protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not even referencing windows forms, wpf or the Console. Startup type: "Windows application".

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.
It feels kind of hacky, but it works reliably.
To explain what it does in short:
1) It collects all current handles of explorer windows and the SHDocVw.IE object behind it (I wonder if there is a better way for this)
2) I am using the absolutely unreliable and weird GetNextWindow() function until I get the first one that was previously collected as explorer handle. This is always the top window. There are usually ~20 handles between the current window and the last selected explorer window.
3) Then I give back the path to the first file selected in that folder window.

This really feels like something that shouldn't be so hard.
I am going over the top with long cat but who cares.
The method should have error handling or checks for undesired states, for example SelectedItems() can be empty or null.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    public static string returnSelectedFile()
    {
        IntPtr windowPtr = GetForegroundWindow();

        Dictionary<string, SHDocVw.InternetExplorer> windows = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, SHDocVw.InternetExplorer>();
        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer window in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
            if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(window.FullName).ToLower().Equals("explorer"))
                windows.Add(window.HWND.ToString(), window);

        long protectionCounter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (windows.ContainsKey(windowPtr.ToString()) || protectionCounter++ > 9999999)
                break;
            windowPtr = GetWindow(windowPtr, 2);
        }
        return ((Shell32.IShellFolderViewDual2)windows[windowPtr.ToString()].Document).SelectedItems().Item(0).Path;
    }
```